# Django app not working externally on Windows Server

Tags: django, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am trying do deploy Django application on Windows Server 2008 using IIS7.

By default in IIS some exemplary page were set on localhost on port 80. And the page were working both on the server and on some computer connected to the server. So everything was fine.

Later I did the steps described on [Matt Woodward's Blog](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html) and set my django application on localhost on port 80 (I deleted the default page). It works on server. But when I connect from external computer I get white page with only two words `invalid request.`

I know that I did not post many details, but maby you have some idea why the first page works fine and the second (django) works only on server.

I guess it's not a problem with firewall (the first page worked).

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I encounter the same, my browser (Chrome)  gives ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT while i have bokeh applications running on other port on the same server that work fine.

Comment: @Joris, as far I remember it was a problem with ALLOWED_HOSTS. When I set ALLOWED_HOSTS=[*] (which I guess is not the best solution) it started to work properly.

Comment: thanks for the update - indeed in ALLOWED_HOST you need to place the or the server id or 'localhost' or * to allow all

Answer (score 1):

In my case this didn't work because Windows firewall was blocking the port.

To open a port in the Windows firewall for TCP access:

1. On the Start menu, click Run, type WF.msc, and then click OK. 2/In
   the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, in the left pane,
   right-click Inbound Rules, and then click New Rule in the action
   pane.
2. In the Rule Type dialog box, select Port, and then
   click Next.
3. In the Protocol and Ports dialog box, select TCP.
   Select Specific local ports, and then type the port number, for
   instance 80 for the default port.
4. In the Action dialog box, select Allow the connection, and then click Next.
5. In the Profile dialog box, select any profiles that describe the
   computer connection environment when you want to connect to the
   Database Engine, and then click Next.
6. In the Name dialog box, type a name and description for this rule, and then click Finish.